# "At this time PowerBI supports only connecting to the Analytics Services tabular models."

Tags: powerbi

I am tying to install Power BI analytics Service Connector tool.

I am getting "At this time PowerBI supports only connecting to the Analytics Services tabular models."

Isn't it possible to connect to the SSAS right now?

Answer (score 0):

Right now the power bi analysis services connector only supports tabular models. Multidimensional models are not yet supported.  Just a quick callout that this info is documented at support.PowerBI.com.

Lukasz